# Azure Logic App SFTP access Fails intermittently with 400 Error BadRequest

Tags: sftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

We have a Azure Logic App which uses SFTP:SSH connector to query SFTP Path (and folders inside it), we pass the required credentials thru the connection and the Logic App Works perfectly fine most of the times but last few days intermittently we are recieving  400 BAD REQUEST ERROR with following error details:-

```
 "status": 400,
  "message": "Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification.\r\nclientRequestId: 836d4958-XXXXXXXXXXXX0fc6194de8",
  "error": {
    "message": "Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification."
  },
```

This is intermittent and we are not getting this error everyday and I am unforunately not able to find any more details in Azure Diagnostics (Log Analytics) other than it reporting it as BAD REQUEST.

```
Name
Check_if_SFMC_Contact_Folder_Accesible

Status
Failed

Duration
0.172

ResourceType
Action

Code
BadRequest

RunId
08586216583846542846119480768CU09

LogicAppName
XXXXX-PROD-APPI-Batch-LAPP-YYYYStatus-Check

StartTime [UTC]
2020-01-25T10:35:01.613Z

EndTime [UTC]
2020-01-25T10:35:01.785Z
```

Can someone help me understand if this is the issue on our Logic App end or possibly on the SFTP Server end which we are trying to accesss?. I think this is coming more from the SFTP Server and Server is rejecting it but I am really not able to find more details.

Any help on this as to what could be causing this issue with the SFTP Access?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you created a support ticket? I had a similar case some time ago and the support team could quickly verify that the problem came from the server side. Would be nice to have more debugging options for the SFTP connector...

Comment: Thank you Esa, I agree with Azure Diagnostics I dont have enough information on this and the SFTP Server guys are saying all is well on their end and infact every other run after this succeeds. I will open the support ticket with Microsoft now and try and get more details. @Esa

Comment: Same issue.  I have this on multiple servers.  Seems to happen under large loads.  Did you ever figure this out?  I wish it would retry, but on a 400 it doesn't.

Comment: No Thomas unfortunately still not found any soln to this issue.